# how to go back to previous page containing selected dropdown data in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a page **A** on which a dropdown is there. On selecting the dropdown value corresponding list come. On clicking one of the names from list, it redirects to another page **B** performing some operations. On page **B** we have a button called **back**. I want that whenever **back** button is pressed it redirects to previous page where list comes based on dropdown value selected. How can I achieve this.??

**pageA.component.html**

```
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 txt-box">
          <div class="runTextBox">
            <select
              type="number"
              class="control"
              (ngModelChange)="onChangeGroup($event)"
            >
              <option hidden value="" disabled="true"
                >Please select Group Name
              </option>
              <option
                *ngFor="let anaName of getGroupList"
                type="number"
                [ngValue]="anaName.Id"
              >
                {{ anaName.GroupName }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

          <div class="list_table">
        <table class="table tabs">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Sub Group Name</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of startedSubGroupList; let x = 
                index">
              <td>
                <a [routerLink]="" 
                 (click)="showSubGroupData(data.Info)"> 
                {{ data.subGroupName}}</a>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

**pageA.componet.ts**

```
 onChangeGroup(value) {
      this.groupId = value;
      this.viewAnaServ.getSubGroupList(value).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.startedSubGroupList = res;
      console.log(this.startedSubGroupList);
  });
}

showSubGroupData(v) {
   this.viewAnaServ.getDataInfo(v)
   this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/anaview/PageB"]);
}
```

**pageB.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     *some operation*
    </div> 
 </div>
 <button (click)="backToPageA()">Back</button>
```

**pageB.component.ts**

```
backToPageA(){
  this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/anaview/PageA"]);
}
```

When group is selected from drop down on PageA, list of sub groups comes. On clicking on one of the sub group it is redirected to pageB. I want that when backToPageA button is clicked it goes to PageA containing selected group along with list of its sub groups.

Comment: please explain in more details so my question is that you want value in dropdown when you click on back button or you want only redirect to that previous page ?

Comment: I want that when i click on back button it show value in dropdown .

Comment: can you share some code here so it will be easy for all

Comment: @KiranMistry I have added some code to it.

Comment: for dropdown value you are using API right ?

Comment: you can pass the selected value as query param to your redirect URL `backToPageA(){
  this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/anaview/PageA?value=1"]);
}` and then get the value in componentA onInit and populate the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via routing in angular. You can create 2 routes, first for page A while second for page B. So when you click on dropdown from page A, you can redirect to page B.
Similarly when you click on **back** button on page B, you can redirect to page A.

Comment: But page "A" shows empty dropdown. I want that when back button from page "B" is clicked, it redirects to page "A" with the selected dropdown.

Comment: how to showing value in dropdown please tell me i will solve your problem